# WordPress: Find out how many times does a user logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any plugin which can help me to find out that how many times does a user have logged in?

It wouldn't be a very complex code to write but i was just wondering if there is already some plugin which provide this feature?

Yes I m using BuddyPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Plugin Called "Simple Login Log". It did exactly what i was looking for

Thanks,

Plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-login-log/

Answer (score 0):

check http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wassup/ for this.. it will help you best with little extentions...

Answer (score 0):

I think  User-Login-Stat does exactly what you describe:

https://github.com/tareq1988/User-Login-Stat